# Find and replace all characters before #

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an array containing strings. Each string looks like this:

```
Debit Card Purchase 06/14 06:09p #1936 UIC CAMPUS PRKG ADMIN CHICAGO IL 16168
```

I would like to remove all before "#" character in order to retain only UIC CAMPUS PRKG ADMIN CHICAGO IL 16168 as a name. How can I use regex scripting to do this in rails?

IF I COULD, I would like to just get UIC CAMPUS PRKG ADMIN but not sure how I can distinguish just this part but not sure if it is possible. Looking for suggestions on that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str = "Debit Card .... PRKG ADMIN CHICAGO IL 16168"`

You could extract the second part by

`str = str.sub(/.*#\d+\s*/, '') = "UIC CAMPUS PRKG ADMIN CHICAGO IL 16168"`

Alternatively you can use split on the string

`str = str.split(/#\d+\s*/).last = "UIC CAMPUS PRKG ADMIN CHICAGO IL 16168"`

Then to remove the city, state and zip

`str = str.sub(/(\s*\w+\s*){2}\d+$/,'') = "UIC CAMPUS PRKG ADMIN"`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
# (s = 'Debit ... IL 16168')
s.sub /.*#\d+ /, '' # => "UIC CAMPUS PRKG ADMIN CHICAGO IL 16168"
```

You would then assign that to another variable or use `s.sub! /.../, ''`